# Reference request: "duality" relations between $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$, $O_q(G)$ and $O_q(G^*)$

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a bialgebra, $\mathfrak{g}^*$ its dual, and $G$ and $G^*$ the corresponding connected simply-connected Poisson-Lie groups. I have repeatedly heard claims of the following flavour, but never found a trace in any of the standard texts I have at hand:

1) The Hopf algebras $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ and $O_q(G)$ are dual, generalising the classical pairing for $U(\mathfrak{g})$ and $O(G)$ (for which I'm also hoping to see a proof).

2) $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ is isomorphic to $O_q(G^*)$, or at least contains the latter.

References/comments regarding the analogous story for $U_h(\mathfrak{g})$ would also be very useful.

Comment: For sl(2) there's a nice exposition of (1) in Kassel's Quantum Groups.

Comment: 1) General Reference, for example, Klymik-Schmudgen Quantum groups and Their representations, Springer 1997, page 327.

Comment: And as for the classical case, though I have to admit I cannot cite a precise reference, the idea goes as follows: $U(\mathfrak g)$ is identified with the space of invariant differential operators supported around the identity and the pairing between $U(\mathfrak g)$ and ${\cal O}(G)$ is precisely the action of such differential operators on functions.

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}$
This is known as the "quantum duality principle". FIrst of all, note that for arbitrary Lie bialgebra there"s no such things as $U_q(\g)$ in general, so everything works for formal deformations. If $\g$ is semisimple this can be turned into statements about the $q$ version. This is due to Drinfeld, and has been done rigorously by Gavarini (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9909071).

He constructs equivalence of categories between the category of quantum envelopping algebra, and quantized formal power series algebras. Informally it maps $U_{\hbar}(\g)$ to the "subalgebra generated by $\hbar g$", denoted by $U_{\hbar}(\g)'$. The latter is then a flat deformation of $\widehat{S}(\g
)$, which you can identify with the completion of $O(G^*)$ at the identity. He also show the existence of a natural Hopf pairing between $U$ and $U'$. To the best of my knowledge, this is actually how you define what is also denoted by $O_{\hbar}(G^*)$ in the general case.

It's instructive to think about the Lie algebra case: $\g^*$ is then abelian, and the Lie bracket on $\g$ gives a Poisson structure on $\g^*$. Now in that case $U_{\hbar}(\g)=U(\g)[[\hbar]]$ is a deformation of the co-Poisson Hopf algebra $U(\g)$ with trivial co-Poisson structure, and $U(\hbar \g)[[\hbar]]$ is a deformation quantization of the Poisson structure on $G^*=(\g^*,+)$, i.e. a deformation of the Poisson algebra $\widehat{O}(G^*)$ whose Poisson structure comes from $\g$.

**Edit:** To extends on the classical case: for the quantization of $\g^*$, it is $S(\g^*)[[\hbar]]$ as an algebra because $\g^*$ is commutative, ie the trvial deformation of poylynomial function on $\g$, and the coproduct should be dual to the bracket of $\g$ at the first order somehow. Indeed it is given by the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula: for $f\in \g^*$, $x,y\in \g$, $$\Delta(f)(x\otimes y)=f(BCH(x,y))$$
Taking again the subalgebra generated by $\hbar\g^*$, you get a flat deformation of $\widehat{S}(\g^*)=\widehat{O(G)}$ and the Hopf pairing is obtained by extending the pairing between $\g$ and $\g^*$. This is a standard fact that it agree with the pairing of Nicola's comment through the BCH formula. Indeed the standard coproduct on $O(G)$ is dual to the product of $G$, which can be expressed through the BCH formula. Hence the above coproduct is nothing but the pull back of the standard one on $O(G)$ through the iso $\widehat{S}(\g^*)\cong \widehat{O(G)}$.

It's worth mentionning that everything can be made fairly explicit in the semi-simple case, I guess it's done in Chari-Pressley. Kassel-Turaev's paper on biquantization of Lie bialgebra is also relevant here.

Comment: See also: Poisson Lie Groups, Quantum Duality Principle, and the Quantum Double  M. A. Semenov-Tian-Shansky http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9304042 . Also F. Gavarini has quite a series of papers on quantum duality.

Comment: I find somehow difficult to understand the "Edit" part. Take GL(n), O(GL_n) = C[t_{ij}] (we can neglect $det \ne 0$) everything is very explicit. How one can construct from a coproduct $detla(t_ij) = \sum_k t_{ik} \otimes t_{kj} $ the commutation relation $[e_{ij}, e_{kl} ] = \delta_{jk} e_{il} - \delta_{li} e_{kj} $ ? Or may be better to ask about upper-triangular 3x3 matrices ...

Comment: Alexander> You can check explicitely that the coproduct you wrote is indeed dual to the multiplication of $GL_n$, which you can relate to the Lie bracket thanks to the BCH formula, so it's consistent whith what I wrote, I think.

Answer (score 1):

These questions are dicussed in

[N. Yu. Reshetikhin, L. A. Takhtadzhyan, L. D. Faddeev, “Quantization of Lie groups and Lie algebras”,](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=aa&paperid=7&option_lang=eng) ([Full text in Russian](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/getFT.phtml?jrnid=aa&paperid=7&volume=1&year=1989&issue=1&fpage=178&what=fullt&option_lang=eng) is available from that page).
Let me follow Russian text in numeration of section and theorems.

You should look at section 2,  theorem 12, page 200.
It says that algebra U_q(h) is isomorphic to (mild extentsion) of Fun_q(G).
The isomorphism is explicitly given on generators for each of classical series A_n,B_n,C_n,D_n. (Exceptional groups seems  not mentioned).

Concerning the proof - the authors write "by direct calculation"...

The previous theorems in section 2, gives R-matrix description of the Fun_q(G)^*.

---

Informal remarks. This fact always seemed and seems now to me, as something surprising and un-understandable, because comultiplication on Fun_q(G) does not depend on "q" - it is standard matrix co-multiplication $\Delta(t_{ij}) = \sum_k t_{ik}\otimes t_{kj} $.

By duality the commultiplication should go to multiplication on U_q(g). 
Multiplication  depends on "q" and looks quite different from the simple formula above $\Delta(t_{ij}) = \sum_k t_{ik}\otimes t_{kj} $. So it is strange how one can match the two. Even for q=1, it seems quite surprising.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I've been unable thus far to obtain an English version of the article...

Comment: In fact the multiplication of $U_q(\mathfrak g)$ depends only apparently on $q$, in the semisimple case. Semisimplicity of $\mathfrak g$ implies rigidity, via the usual cohomological argument; thus any Lie algebraic deformation of $\mathfrak g$ is again isomorphic to $\mathfrak g$. This, in turn, implies that $U(\mathfrak g)$ is rigid as an associative algebra. Therefore there is an algebra isomorphism from $U(\mathfrak g)$ to $U_q(\mathfrak g)$ for any $q$. Obviously this isomorphism is far from explicit...

Comment: @NicolaCiccoli Yes, you are right. But even for q=1, I am surprised since the two algebras seems very different. Concerning general "q" as far as I understand one precisely needs Drinfeld's associator to construct algebra ismorphism U_q(g) and U(g), but here we have something in the same spirit without such a big thing...